# continuous variable as random effect in proc mixed

Tags: sas, mixed-models

I could use some help understanding the interpretation of a continuous variable random effect. I understand the interpretation of fixed effect and categorical random effect. But SAS seems to allow continuous random effect as well (code below). I understand how random effects are supposed to be categorical, but I came across discussions/forums where arguments were made for continuous random effects as well, hence SAS having that option I guess. But , I am more so trying to understand what do I make of the variance estimate and the coefficient estimate you get in such scenario.
For example we are trying to predict wealth based on  education and age. And, we made age as random effect. The code would look like

`Proc mixed data=data;
model wealth = education;
random age /solution;
run;`

I got the covariance parameter estimate for the random effect age.notice i dont have class statement. I understand, it deosn't make sense to have age as random effect, but I am trying to understand whats going on behind in the sas in the above code. Also, is the random coefficient estimate for age which is truncated towards 0 comparable to fixed effect coefficient when age is fixed?

Thanks in advance.